# e2e protractor test requiring oauth authentication

Tags: angularjs, oauth, protractor, angularjs-e2e

I've got an Angular app that requires authentication with Google, granting of some scopes, etc, and I'm trying to set up automatic e2e tests for it.  I have protractor working well for me in general, but when we get to the google auth page, login, and get redirected, protractor fails the test because "document unloaded while waiting for result."

Is there a tool or technique I can use to authenticate to a development google account beforeEach test?

If I could just get the framework to hold on for a second while plain-old webdriver drives the login, and only really activate the angular stuff after I get to my target page, that would be perfect!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `waitForAngularEnabled` to enable/disable waiting for Angular tasks with protractor. By default it will be enabled. You can use the following:

```
// do things on your Angular application
// go to external oauth page

waitForAngularEnabled(false)

// login on oauth page and redirect to your Angular application

waitForAngularEnabled(true)
browser.get('/home') // this is a page from your Angular application
```

`waitForAngularEnabled` returns a promise. The `browser.get` function blocks until the Angular page is loaded.

Comment: I don't know why this is downvoted.  Can this be clarified?  The answer posted by demee and Riley Lark  works but now that `waitForAngularEnabled` is available we should use that instead of sleep timers.  Set the timer too high and your tests will take long, set them too low and your tests may fail.  This answer will immediately continue with testing your Angular application the moment we switch back from the oauth page.

Answer (score 21):

The key is to use `browser.driver.get` instead of `browser.get`, and to use `browser.driver.sleep(someMilliseconds)` to let angular load at your final destination before using the angular-specific commands.

Here's my working protractor spec that first authorizes to Google and then counts the items in a repeater:

```
it('allows the user to add new slides', function () {
    browser.driver.get('http://localhost:3000/editor/?state=%7B"action":"create"%7D');

    // at this point my server redirects to google's auth page, so let's log in
    var emailInput = browser.driver.findElement(by.id('Email'));
    emailInput.sendKeys('user@googleappsdomain.com');

    var passwordInput = browser.driver.findElement(by.id('Passwd'));
    passwordInput.sendKeys('pa$sWo2d');  //you should not commit this to VCS

    var signInButton = browser.driver.findElement(by.id('signIn'));
    signInButton.click();

    // we're about to authorize some permissions, but the button isn't enabled for a second
    browser.driver.sleep(1500);

    var submitApproveAccess = browser.driver.findElement(by.id('submit_approve_access'));
    submitApproveAccess.click();

    // this nap is necessary to let angular load.
    browser.driver.sleep(10000);

    // at this point the protractor functions have something to hook into and 
    // will work as normal!
    element(by.id('new-slide-dropdown-trigger')).click();
    element(by.id('new-text-slide-trigger')).click();

    var slideList = element.all(by.repeater('slide in deck.getSlides()'));
    slideList.then(function(slideElements) {
        expect(slideElements.length).toEqual(1);
    });

});
```

Comment: I would use seeps in protractor tests as the last resource.

Comment: Rather than sleeping for an indeterminate time, why not wait for an element to change in the DOM?

Answer (score 8):

I have a Google Auth page object (below) that does the whole job for me.

The key here is "isAngularSite(false);" function witch instructs webdriver if we are entering 'angular' or 'non angular' website. 
(implementation below).

```
/* global element, browser, by */

'use strict';

var GOOGLE_USERNAME = 'my.account@google.com';
var GOOGLE_PASSWORD = 'password';
var ec = protractor.ExpectedConditions;

var Google = function () {
  this.emailInput = element(by.id('Email'));
  this.passwordInput = element(by.id('Passwd'));
  this.nextButton = element(by.id('next'));
  this.signInButton = element(by.id('signIn'));
  this.approveAccess = element(by.id('submit_approve_access'));

  this.loginToGoogle = function () {
    var self = this;

    /* Entering non angular site, it instructs webdriver to switch 
       to synchronous mode. At this point I assume we are on google
       login page */ 
    isAngularSite(false); 
    this.emailInput.sendKeys(GOOGLE_USERNAME);
    this.nextButton.click();

    this.passwordInput.isPresent().then(function () {
      browser.wait(ec.visibilityOf(self.passwordInput), BROWSER_WAIT).then(function () {
        self.passwordInput.sendKeys(GOOGLE_PASSWORD);
        self.signInButton.click();
        browser.wait(ec.elementToBeClickable(self.approveAccess), BROWSER_WAIT).then(function () {
          self.approveAccess.click();
          /* Now we are being redirected to our app, switch back to
             async mode (page with angular) */
          isAngularSite(true);
        });
      });
    });
  }
}

module.exports = new Google();
```

--- throw this into protractor.conf.js

```
onPrepare: function () {
    global.isAngularSite = function (flag) {
      console.log('Switching to ' + (flag ? 'Asynchronous' : 'Synchronous') + ' mode.')
      browser.ignoreSynchronization = !flag;
    },
    global.BROWSER_WAIT = 5000;
  }
```

--- that's how you would use it:

```
it('should login though google', function(done) {
    mainPage.loginBtn.click().
    then(function () {
      loginPage.connectWithGoogleBtn.click();
      googlePage.loginToGoogle();
      browser.wait(mainPage.userName.isPresent()).
      then(function () {
        expect(mainPage.userName.getText()).
        toEqual('my.account@google.com');
        done();
      });
    });
  });
```

Comment: Sorry for the long time until comment, but what are mainPage and loginPage? They aren't defined anywhere.

Comment: mainPage and logingPage are basically your page objects that you might have in you testing framework... although you can just remove those variables and the code would make similar sense

Comment: Ok, so what about the googlePage variable - how can I use the first code, I currently have it in another file that gets called in specs. Is that right - sorry for the newb questions, I could probably use a chat.