# AngularJS Protractor - How Do You Test an AJAX Login Call?

Tags: javascript, jasmine, protractor

I have a button that once clicked sends out an AJAX call in Angular's `$promise` format.  When the login is successful, a `$scope` variable is changed and an element that looks like:

```
<section id="logged-in-section" ng-if="auth.user !== null">
    // Section to display if logged in
</section>
```

is displayed.  I am currently testing the above with the following:

```
loginButton.click();
browser.sleep(2000);
expect($("#logged-in-section").isDisplayed()).toBeTruthy();
```

`browser.sleep(2000)` idles the browser for two seconds before Protractor checks to see if `logged-in-section` has been displayed.  If I take out `browser.sleep(2000)`, the test fails since there is a lag between hitting the login button and the response returned from the server.

What's the syntax to chain the login button to the `expect` statement so that Protractor is only checking for `#logged-in-section` after the `$promise` is returned?

Comment: possible duplicate of [e2e protractor test requiring oauth authentication](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20959748/e2e-protractor-test-requiring-oauth-authentication)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
loginButton.click().then(function(){
   browser.waitForAngular().then(function (){ //this should wait for the angular digest process to finish
      expect($("#logged-in-section").isDisplayed()).toBeTruthy();
   })
});
```

or this should works to:

```
loginButton.click().then(function(){
   browser.wait(element(by.id("logged-in-section")).isDisplayed);
   expect($("#logged-in-section").isDisplayed()).toBeTruthy();
});
```