# Google Authentication with Protractor

Tags: angularjs, protractor, google-oauth

I have only been able to track down [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20959748/e2e-protractor-test-requiring-oauth-authentication/33831771?noredirect=1#comment74227812_33831771) to solve my problem. I am trying to use protractor to run e2e testing. This is my first go at it, and I like it. However my project requires Google Authentication, then once authenticated, I compare it to my database to make sure the user is in the project. I cannot figure out from the stackoverflow post how to call to the Google Auth page object demee is talking about in the last answer. Also the first person says to find element by.id('Email') and by.id('Passwd') which may be a problem, because my google auth is coming up in another window. So I am not sure how to call to that with Protractor. Here is some of my code after I initialize the $window once gapi is loaded:

```
.controller('ContainerController', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$state','$window', '$location','employeeFactory', 'employeeTestFactory', function ($scope, $rootScope, $state, $window,$location, employeeFactory, employeeTestFactory) {
        $rootScope.callRequests=function(){};
        $rootScope.callInfo=function(){};
        if(typeof $rootScope.gapi !== "undefined")gapi.load('client:auth2', initClient);
        $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){
            if(typeof $rootScope.gapi === "undefined") return;
            gapi.load('client:auth2', initClient);
        })
        $scope.$state = $state;
        $window.initGapi = function() {
            gapi.load('client:auth2', initClient);
            $rootScope.gapi = gapi;
        }
        $rootScope.calculateUsed = function(val){
            $rootScope.employee.timePending = $rootScope.employee.timePending = 0;
            var newTimeUsed = 0;
            angular.forEach(val, function(key, value){
                var td = key.timeDuration;
                if(key.timeState === "pending"){
                    $rootScope.employee.timePending += Number(td);
                }else{
                    newTimeUsed += Number(td);
                }
            });
            $rootScope.employee.totalTimeUsed = newTimeUsed;
        }

        $scope.employeeType = $rootScope.email = "";
        function initClient() {
            gapi.client.init({
                apiKey: 'AIzaSyDaMf0eviuFygt1hzwQz03a2k2lrLDnpIc',
                discoveryDocs: ["https://people.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v1"],
                clientId: '977491754644-954b83j2evmq65v6kchq4dsd9j0ud4vg.apps.googleusercontent.com',
                scope: 'profile'
            }).then(function () {                    gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.listen(updateSigninStatus);                    updateSigninStatus(gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.get());
                $scope.employee = [];
            });
        }

        function updateSigninStatus(isSignedIn) {
            if (isSignedIn) {
                getEmailAddress();
            }else{
                $state.go('app');
            }
        }

        $scope.handleSignInClick = function(event) {
            if(!gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.get()){
                gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signIn();
            }
        }

        $scope.handleSignOutClick = function(event) {
            if(gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.get()){
                gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signOut();
            }
        }

        function getEmailAddress() {
            gapi.client.people.people.get({
                resourceName: 'people/me'
            }).then(function(response) {

                $rootScope.email = response.result.emailAddresses[0].value;
                $rootScope.callRequests();
                $rootScope.callInfo();
        //Here is where I compare google to my db and route users back to main if not in db                employeeTestFactory.get($rootScope.email).then(function(message) {
                    if(typeof message.employeeid === "undefined"){
                        $state.go('app');
                    }else if($location.path() === "/"){
                        $state.go('app.employee');
                        $rootScope.employee = message;

                    }else{
                        $rootScope.employee = message;

                    }
                });

            }, function(reason) {
                console.log('Error: ' + reason.result.error.message);
            });
        }
    }])

    .controller('LoginController', ['$scope', '$state', '$window', '$http','$rootScope', '$timeout', 'GooglePlus', 'gapiService', function ($scope, $state, $window, $http, $rootScope, $timeout, GooglePlus, gapiService) {

        $scope.$state = $state;
        $scope.callme = function(){
            $scope.handleSignInClick();
        }


        // if it could not be loaded, try the rest of
        // the options. if it was, return it.

        var url;
        var windowThatWasOpened;

        $http.get("url").then(function(response) {
            url = response.data;
        });

        $scope.login = function() {
            windowThatWasOpened = $window.open(url, "Please sign in with Google", "width=500px,height=700px");
        }


        window.onmessage = function(e) {

            if(windowThatWasOpened) windowThatWasOpened.close();
            var urlWithCode = e.data;

            var idx = urlWithCode.lastIndexOf("code=");
            if(idx === -1) return;
            var code = urlWithCode.substring(idx + 5).replace("#","");

            $http.get("token?code=" + code).then(function(response) {
                var userurl = 'https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me?access_token='+response.data.access_token;
                $http.get(userurl).then(function(response) {
                    console.log("user info: "+JSON.stringify(response.data));
                })
            });


        } 
    }])
```

And here is the code I am trying to navigate to google with:

```
describe('Protractor Demo App', function() {
  it('should have a title', function() {
    browser.get('http://localhost:9000/');

    element(by.id('gLogin')).click().then(function(){
      Google.loginToGoogle();
    });

    expect(browser.getTitle()).toEqual('TrinityIT Time Off Tracking');

     browser.sleep(5000);
  });
});
```

And here is my conf file:

```
exports.config = {
  framework: 'jasmine',
  specs: ['googlePage.js','spec.js'],
  onPrepare: function () {
    global.isAngularSite = function (flag) {
      console.log('Switching to ' + (flag ? 'Asynchronous' : 'Synchronous') + ' mode.')
      browser.ignoreSynchronization = !flag;
    },
      global.BROWSER_WAIT = 5000;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that what you're looking to do is test your app, rather than test the OAuth dialogue, then there is an easier approach.

First an OAuth refresher, the whole point of doing all the OAuth stuff is that you end up with an Access Token that you can include as an "Authorization: Bearer xxxxx" HTTP Header with your Google API (eg. Drive, YouTube, Calendar, etc) requests. Sooooooo, if you had an Access Token, you could bypass all the OAuth stuff and your app will be active and able to be tested.

So, what you want is an automated way to get an Access Token. That's pretty simple. Somewhere, either in your app code or in your Protractor preamble scripts, you need to ingest a Refresh Token, and use that to generate an Access Token which is available to your app.

I do this with a file `refreshtoken.js` which I carefully do NOT check in to git for security reasons. `refreshtoken.js` is

```
var refreshtoken="1x97e978a7a0977...";
var client_id="423432423@gfgfd";
```

If you look at the answer to [How do I authorise an app (web or installed) without user intervention? (canonical ?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19766912/how-do-i-authorise-an-app-web-or-installed-without-user-intervention-canonic), you will see the steps to get a Refresh Token, and at the bottom, some JavaScript to show how to use the Refresh Token to fetch an Access Token. It might look like a lot of steps, but you only ever do them once, so it's not too onerous.

This approach bypasses OAuth, so isn't the answer if it's specifically OAuth that you want to test. However it does allow you to test your app in a much more robust manner. It also has the benefit that it can be used for Karma unit testing as well as Protractor e2e testing.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I kept getting stuck on step 9, I get the following error: "oauthplayground, does not match the ones authorized for the OAuth client." I was trying to use gplus instead of drive like your link told to use. But they said it would work for any of them.

Comment: make sure the redirect URL you specify in the API console is EXACTLY (character for character) "https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground"

Comment: Yeah I think I need to add "Protractor preamble scripts" to get the refresh token. Can you point me to a place to figure that out?

Comment: the JS to get an Access Token is in the SO question I linked to. Tiy could probably put that in an onPrepare - see https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/spec/withLoginConf.js

Comment: I am getting an error from that other page's code. Says "Headers is not defined". I found out that is experimental code, does it work with Protractor?

Comment: I'd need to see your code and where the error message is coming from

Comment: I am using the code from the other site. It says it is failing on this line:
"headers: new Headers({" and it says Error: ReferenceError: Headers is not defined

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143314/discussion-between-todd-coulson-and-pinoyyid).